# Is order important in Structural Equivalence?

Tags: compilers, types

From 6.3.2 of Aho *et al.*

> When type expressions are represented by graphs, two types are
> structurally equivalent if and only if one of the following conditions
> is true:
>
> - They are the same basic type.
> - They are formed by applying the same constructor to structurally equivalent types.
> - One is a type name that denotes the other.
>
> If type names are treated as standing for themselves, then the first
> two conditions in the above definition lead to name equivalence of
> type expressions.

1. What do they mean by *formed by applying the same constructor*?
2. If we consider the following in C

```
typedef struct a{
    int x;
    float y;
} a;

typedef struct b{
    float y;
    int x;
} b;
```

By the book's definition, would `a` and `b` be structurally equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

A type constructor is a way to build a type from other types (possibly zero other types), in the same way that a value constructor is a way to build a value from (possibly 0) other values. Constructors are usually identified by a name. The details can vary between programming languages; in my examples I'll use a syntax similar to ML (but with type constructors prefixed, not postfixed) and Haskell.

For example, `int` is a type expression, whose values are integers (within a range that depends on the implementation). `list(int)` is a type expression, whose values are lists of integers. `list` is a type constructor that takes one argument (the type of the list elements). `int` is a type constructor that takes zero arguments. `int * float` is a type expression, whose values are pairs consisting of one integer and one floating-point value. `*` is a type constructor that takes two arguments (the type of the first value and the type of the second value). `int -> float` is a type expression, whose values are functions from integers to floats. `->` is a type constructor that takes two arguments (the domain and the range of the function).

Two type expressions are structurally equivalent if they are essentially the same type, but using different names. For example, after a definition

```
type int_list = list(int)
```

the types `int_list * float` and `list(int) * float` are structurally equivalent, since `int_list` is s.e. to `list(int)` (rule 3), `float` is s.e. to `float` (rule 1), and applying the type constructor `*` to s.e. types yields s.e. types (rule 2).

In simple cases, two type expressions are structurally equivalent if you get the exact same expression after expanding all type abbreviations in both. However, this necessarily doesn't work with recursive type definitions, where expanding all abbreviations might not terminate.

You can't reorder the arguments of a type constructor. That results in a different type. `int * float` and `float * int` are not structurally equivalent. Intuitively, their values have different shapes. If you had a computer where `int` and `float` values are stored in different kinds of memory cells, the two types would need to be stored differently. This is more obvious if you consider the function type constructor: `int -> float` and `float -> int` are completely unrelated types.

Intuitively, if two types $T_1$ and $T_2$ are structurally equivalent, then they have the same memory layout. You can write a value of type $T_1$ in memory, and read it back as type $T_2$. (An implementation doesn't have to follow this property, but if it doesn't, that would likely mean that the formalization of the type system is missing some information about the language.) Note that the converse is not true: it's common to have different types with the same layout in memory. For example, in C, `struct {int a;}` and `struct {int b;}` have the same layout in memory (and you can cast pointers between the two), but they aren't compatible types (you can't assign from one directly to the other). Furthermore, many languages treat some structurally equivalent types as distinct: that's the whole point of having [abstract types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type).

A pair of types like `(int * float, float * int)` or the two structures in your question are not structurally equivalent. They aren't compatible and they don't have the same layout in memory. They do have an interesting property that you can build a pair of bijections between the two types that obeys the structure of the data. I don't know if there's an established name for this kind of equivalence; it's a kind of structural or algebraic isomorphism.